# Samsung galaxy s2 upgrade problem

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, device-firmware, odin

I want to upgrade my Android version 2.3 to the newest firmware version. I am using Odin v3.04 but when I put file into the PDA section and turned the phone into download mode and started the upgrade process it FAILED. I then tried to reconnect my USB and try again, but now it hangs on SetupConnection:

```
<ID:0/006> File analysis..
<ID:0/006> SetupConnection..
```

It also doesn't turn on in download mode. When I turn the phone on it immediately goes to screen with a yellow triangle and computer and will not do anything else.

What can I do to fix this?